# Constructor parameters not known inside onCreate method of Service Class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, android-notifications

```
``package com.arkenstonestudio.docxscanner.Notification;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.arkenstonestudio.docxscanner.LauncherActivity;
import com.arkenstonestudio.docxscanner.R;

public class ShowNotification extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "ShowNotification";
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int presetOption = 0;

    public void notificationValues(int presetOptionX){

       this.presetOption = presetOptionX; // 3 int value here is not known in onCreate
        Log.i(TAG, "Constructor: "+ this.presetOption);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: "+presetOption); // 0 int value is shown here instead of 3

        //Notification Preset1
        String titledText1 = "Scan Docs With A.I Filters";
        String someBigText1 = "It's been a long time since no document is scanned...";
        if (presetOption == 1)
        {
            createNotification(titledText1, someBigText1);
        }
        else if (presetOption == 2)
        {
            //notification Preset2
            String titledText2 = "Try ID Car Scan";
            String someBigText2 = "Best ever ID card scanning let you scan both side of ID Card on same page more visible";
            createNotification(titledText2, someBigText2);
        }else if (presetOption == 3)
        {
            //notification Preset3
            String titledText3 = "Try Digital Signature";
            String someBigText3 = "Draw or Import digital signature and place it on any document you want.";
            createNotification(titledText3, someBigText3);
        }else if (presetOption == 4)
        {
            //notification Preset4
            String titledText4 = "D.S.P Ocr feature";
            String someBigText4 = "Let's convert text image into editable text for you...";
            createNotification(titledText4, someBigText4);
        }
        else
        {
            createNotification(titledText1, someBigText1);
        }


    }

    private void createNotification(String titledTxt, String bigTxt){

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notify_001");
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LauncherActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, ii, 0);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.docx_scan_trans);
            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }

        mBuilder.setContentTitle(titledTxt);
        mBuilder.setContentText(bigTxt);
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText);

        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // === Removed some obsoletes
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId = "dsp-rc-123";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "Docx scanner Plus",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification created");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}`
```

`
**I am trying above code where I use constructor for initialization of int value and then I try to access that value inside onCreate method but the problem is that int value inside onCreate method is always 0 while the value is shown correctly inside constructor. Anyone can help me with that...Thanks in Advance.**

Screenshot is shown for more clarification:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmani.png)

All I want to access the constructor value and assign it to variable inside class so that to make it global.

I did not find any suitable answer related to my problem on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the constructor to pass a certain value in an application context, you should try to pass it as a Bundle to the OnCreate function. Here is a link to the documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle . ` @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle putYourInfoHere) {
super.onCreate(putYourInfoHere);

```
    this.presetOption = putYoutInfoHere.getInt

    //Notification Preset1
    String titledText1 = "Scan Docs With A.I Filters";
    String someBigText1 = "It's been a long time since no document is scanned...";
    if (presetOption == 1)
    {
        createNotification(titledText1, someBigText1);
    }
    else if (presetOption == 2)
    {
        //notification Preset2
        String titledText2 = "Try ID Car Scan";
        String someBigText2 = "Best ever ID card scanning let you scan both side of ID Card on same page more visible";
        createNotification(titledText2, someBigText2);
    }else if (presetOption == 3)
    {
        //notification Preset3
        String titledText3 = "Try Digital Signature";
        String someBigText3 = "Draw or Import digital signature and place it on any document you want.";
        createNotification(titledText3, someBigText3);
    }else if (presetOption == 4)
    {
        //notification Preset4
        String titledText4 = "D.S.P Ocr feature";
        String someBigText4 = "Let's convert text image into editable text for you...";
        createNotification(titledText4, someBigText4);
    }
    else
    {
        createNotification(titledText1, someBigText1);
    }


}`
```

I am assuming that you get you're presetValue in your constructor from another page. If so, you should implement a function to store the value in your Bundle as shown in the documentation.